# rails 3 destroy action fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The destroy action:

```
def destroy
  @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
  @tag.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to(tags_url) }
    format.xml  { head :ok }
  end
end
```

The link:

```
<a href="/tags/14" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a>
```

Clicking it renders the show action.

```
Started GET "/tags/14" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Oct 27 18:36:41 -0500 2010
Processing by TagsController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"14"}
Tag Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE ("tags"."id" = 14) LIMIT 1
Rendered tags/show.html.erb within layouts/application (8.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 25ms (Views: 12.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

javascript_include_tag :defaults is included on my page and the script tags render correctly. Firebug doesn't give me any errors. This occurs in both Firefox and Opera.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably how you are writing your link_to method.

```
 <%= link_to "Destroy", tag, :method => :delete, :confirm => "Really?" %>
```

Try that.

---

Make sure you have the resource declared in your routes.rb file as that is what gives this freebee urls.

in 2.3.8 it is

```
map.resources :tags
```

in R3 I don't really know but the guides have it like this

```
resources :tags
```

Comment: It is written like that. only difference is that the order of the :confirm and :method params is reversed. I switched them just in case that would matter, but it didn't.

Comment: Are you declaring this in your routes file. This routes are only avaliable if you have map.resources :resource declared. At least this is how 2.3.8 does it, I haven't upgraded yet.

Comment: I do have resources :tags in my routes.

Comment: I already put the only relevant log info in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

To use method overriding you need to be sending the `_method` parameter. For an action like destroy it should be a form that you POST with the `_method` parameter set to `delete`, you can construct the form in JS when you click the link if you like.